# DooPHP :: filemtime(): stat failed for VIEW_FILENAME.html

Tags: php, filemtime, doophp

I'm using Doophp framework and its working perfectly on localhost and xampp but I get `filemtime(): stat failed for view_filename.html` on web host. Is that a host-side error or framework bug?
what do you recommend for this error.
[here is full stack trace](http://mhesabi.eclick.ir/creattica/Members)

Comment: It's probably due to your file permission settings for that file. nothing to do with doophp

Comment: @mauris what permission is fine for this purpose, 777?

Comment: @mhesabi - there is your config in posted stack trace, better change your gmail password, and  carefully check what you are sharing in the future

Comment: thanks for mention that still that mail is dummy anyhow. btw changed permission settings also filemtime has absolute path to the file but it returns error yet